# Why a particular species of bacteria give rise to particular type of colony?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

Bacterial colony varies in form, elevation, margin, opacity, chromogenesis etc. What gives definite character to a colony and what is the source of all the diversity? Is the reason similar to that of structure of salt crystal (i.e basic elements connect in a very definite way with each other)?

**UPDATE** (clarification)

On [this page](http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/MicroBio_Interpreting_Plates.shtml), it is observed that colonies can take various shapes, as if they have some internal structure, so that for example, form, elevation and margin differ and can even be described as having a particular shape.

Assuming that bacteria do not have any form of social organization or specification, what factors cause their colonies to have a particular shape, and that shape is well-defined for each species?

Also, for example, [this picture](http://www.gmilburn.ca/wp-content/media/bacteria_plate.jpg) on [this website](http://www.gmilburn.ca/2008/12/06/the-trees-of-mars/) clearly shows a bacteria colony that is like ice crystals. If bacteria colony has no inner structure, what makes the bacteria to follow such a crystal-like pattern? Why not a shapeless goo, as one would imagine?

Comment: It all depends on the gene expression of the component cells, and their interactions between each other.

Comment: Different bacteria types are different species of animals. And different animals can have anything different, so there's no surprise to that. For example, it is obvious that cats have different lives than ants or monkeys, and so on.

Comment: @noncom The question is not why bacteria is the way it is rather why it has a distinctive colony? Why is it not random or different in each time?

Comment: So you mean that different bacteria form some sort of a macrostructure and that macrostructure is different per bacteria type?  Also, you ask how the form and structure of that colony is influenced by properties of a particular bacteria species? And ask if that formation is akin to how molecules form a crystal, likening bacteria to crystal molecules?

Comment: @noncom exactly!

Comment: This should not have been closed.

Comment: To me, this has gone from an unclear question to a broad question.

Comment: @GoodGravy is it hard to sum up the reasons for at least one of the relevant cases? Would it take more than a single paragraph to at least make an overview approach to the answer? It does not seem like if the reason for why bacteria colonies form their shapes is known, it would take more than a normal length answer to make an excursion into that.

Comment: @noncom Gauging an appropriate level of detail is tricky. I could simply say: "different environmental stresses causes different gene expression causes different proteins, and the proteins cause the cells to assemble in different ways. Each species reacts differently to their environment (and some will do the same thing in any environment)." A good question in my opinion would ask about a particular species and why it adopts a certain shape.

Comment: @GoodGravy I agree, and at the same time what you're saying is actually a rather appropriate answer to the question (imho). The authors main question was if this phenomenon is related to how crystals grow. The growth of a crystal is defined by molecular and atomic properties of the compound, and in case with bacteria you have specified the focus on gene expression and protein workings. Can they be likened to each other? That's a subject for furhter research of course. Also, I agree that asking on a particular case would be easier to answer precisely.